# Django Rest Framework Reverse Relationship Breaks When Behind Proxy

Tags: django, apache, proxy, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am trying to serve a django webapp which uses gunicorn with httpd acting as a proxy which also serves static content. Everything works fine, except that the django rest framework searchable API root (the entry point for the app's API) does not provide the correct url. The url is for localhost and the port served by gunicorn rather than the ipaddress of the machine or or its host name. Here's httpd conf file for the app:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /opt/example
    ProxyPass /static/ !
    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/static/
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
 </VirtualHost>
```

Gunicorn serves on localhost on port 8000.

Here's the view for the api:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'activity': reverse('activity-list', request=request, format=format)
        'test' : reverse('test-list', request=request, format=format)
    })
```

When hitting the api root page this is the response I get:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "activity": "http://localhost:8000/activity/",
    "tests": "http://localhost:8000/test/",
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar setup and it seems to work just fine.

Make sure you have `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` in your settings.py as it defaults to `False`

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#use-x-forwarded-host)

Comment: Shortest answer ever.  But useful and surprisingly difficult to find by searching.  Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

In your httpd.conf there is a typo `httpd`.

The line should be:

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```

Comment: Sadly, that was just a typo in copying. That typo isn't there in the actual file. I went ahead and edited my question, thanks for the catch.